# How can I change directory to a folder on my mapped network drive in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

Ok so I'm learning terminal.

I'm trying to cd to folder:
/network/NAS/Z-1/1 Video/1 Video

After running df, the NAS volume (Windows 10 volumed on my home network btw) is mounted in "/Volumes/Z-1/" (Not sure why my "Z" folder was renamed to "Z-1"?)

Anyways, so I can change my directory to the "Z" folder (or "Z-1") on the NAS drive, but I can't change my directory to the "1 Video" folder inside the "Z" folder.

I've tried using:

cd /volumes/z-1/1 video

I've also tried using an underscore inbetween 1 and video.

Here's an image for reference:
https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5479/31877442890_fa59725704_o.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Use a backslash:
cd /volumes/z-1/1\ video